# Empty CSS files generated through asset pipeline

Tags: asset-pipeline, hugo

## Problem:

I have a Hugo site with pretty standard setup. It uses asset pipeline to process SASS. It imports bootstrap, font-awesome, and also uses `resources.ExecuteAsTemplate` (please do check out main.css file). CSS resources are being generated properly (I checked `resources/_gen/assets/scss/sass`) but the `.css` file in public directory is an empty file. I am not able to find any problems in the code. See the code [here](https://gitlab.com/Softorage/softorage.gitlab.io), site [here](https://softorage.com). I tried creating a new project with same `head.html` file and `.scss` files, and it generated CSS resources, and had them in the public directory properly.

## Additional info:

1. Related files:
   [head.html](https://gitlab.com/Softorage/softorage.gitlab.io/blob/master/layouts/partials/head.html)
   [main.scss](https://gitlab.com/Softorage/softorage.gitlab.io/blob/master/assets/sass/main.scss)
2. Currently, I am not using PostCSS; just have the config file created. Would be replacing `minify` with `postCSS` on line 13 in head.html once *empty .css file problem* is solved.
3. Output of `hugo version`:
   `Hugo Static Site Generator v0.57.2-A849CB2D/extended linux/amd64 BuildDate: 2019-08-17T17:57:54Z`

I would gladly provide any additional information if required. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `head.html` file, link tag is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" integrity="{{ $css.Data.Integrity }}" href="{{ $css.Permalink }}">
```

Changing the link tag with following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ $css.Permalink }}" integrity="{{ $css.Data.Integrity }}">
```

fixes the issue.

It seems that Hugo requires user to first call `.Permalink` of the asset and then only other related functions or variables.

See related discussion on Hugo Discourse [here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/empty-css-files-generated-through-asset-pipeline/20481).